# Why do I keep getting this cursed SQL*Plus invalid identifier error?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc, ora-00904

I keep getting a invalid identifier exception when I try to run the below script:
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.sql.SQLException: [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-00904: "CUSTID": invalid identifier

```
   Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver"); 
   conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:rreOracle","xxxxxx","xxxxxxxx"); 
   stmt = conn.createStatement(); 
  PreparedStatement preparedStatement;

      //get parameters from the request
      String custID=request.getParameter("cust_ID");
      String saleID=request.getParameter("sale_ID");
      String firstName=request.getParameter("first_Name");
      String mInitial=request.getParameter("mI");
      String lastName=request.getParameter("last_Name");
      String streetName=request.getParameter("street");
      String city=request.getParameter("city");
      String state=request.getParameter("state");
      String zipCode=request.getParameter("zip_Code");
      String DOB=request.getParameter("DOB");
      String agentID=request.getParameter("agent_ID");
      String homePhone=request.getParameter("home_Phone");
      String cellPhone=request.getParameter("cell_Phone");
      String profession=request.getParameter("profession");
      String employer=request.getParameter("employer");
      String referrer=request.getParameter("referrer");


   preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE customer"
+ " SET customer.cust_ID=?, customer.sale_ID=?, customer.first_Name=?, customer.mI=?, customer.last_Name=?, customer.street_Name=?, customer.city=?, customer.state=?, customer.zip_Code=?,customer. DOB=?, customer.agent_ID=?, customer.home_Phone=?, customer.cell_Phone=?, customer.profession=?, customer.employer=?, customer.referrer=?"
+ " WHERE customer.cust_ID=custID ") ;

   preparedStatement.setInt(1, Integer.valueOf(custID));
   preparedStatement.setInt(2, Integer.valueOf(saleID));
   preparedStatement.setString(3, firstName);
   preparedStatement.setString(4, mInitial);
   preparedStatement.setString(5, lastName);
   preparedStatement.setString(6, streetName);
   preparedStatement.setString(7, city);
   preparedStatement.setString(8, state);
   preparedStatement.setString(9, zipCode);
   preparedStatement.setString(10, DOB);
   preparedStatement.setInt(11, Integer.valueOf(agentID));
   preparedStatement.setString(12, homePhone);
   preparedStatement.setString(13, cellPhone);
   preparedStatement.setString(14, profession);
   preparedStatement.setString(15, employer);
   preparedStatement.setString(16, referrer);

   preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: You're not using SQL*Plus, it seems...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can try

```
<%preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE customer"
+ " SET customer.cust_ID=?, customer.sale_ID=?, customer.first_Name=?, customer.mI=?, customer.last_Name=?, customer.street_Name=?, customer.city=?, customer.state=?, customer.zip_Code=?,customer. DOB=?, customer.agent_ID=?, customer.home_Phone=?, customer.cell_Phone=?, customer.profession=?, customer.employer=?, customer.referrer=?"
+ " WHERE customer.cust_ID=?") ;%>
<%preparedStatement.setString(17, custID );%>
```

or

```
<%preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE customer"
+ " SET customer.cust_ID=?, customer.sale_ID=?, customer.first_Name=?, customer.mI=?, customer.last_Name=?, customer.street_Name=?, customer.city=?, customer.state=?, customer.zip_Code=?,customer. DOB=?, customer.agent_ID=?, customer.home_Phone=?, customer.cell_Phone=?, customer.profession=?, customer.employer=?, customer.referrer=?"
+ " WHERE customer.cust_ID="+custID ) ;%>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Himanshu!!! That did it.  You don't know how much I really appreciate it.  I mistakenly assumed that the "custID" in question was the first one which drove me insane, but it was the 2nd one.  Woooooooow.  I will never forget that ever in life again that when equating a column to a value, the value isnt enclosed in quotation marks - basic programming 101 now that I think of it. Thanks again!!!!

Answer (score 3):

In this part of your statement "WHERE customer.cust_ID=custID" oracle is looking for a value called "custID".

At that point,the variable names in your context aren't relevant - inside the SQL an "where A=B" statement refers to "column A == column B" - since there's not "custID" column in the table, oracle complains.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Steve. Your explanation added to the correction above from Himanshu did the trick.  I see what I was doing wrong.  Thanks a million!!!